# Different result about "words ending with w" in Wolframalpha and Mathematica 11.0

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, dictionary

Why there are different result

[image]

There are  $691$ words according the [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=words+ending+with+w).

but there are only $307$ words according the *Wolfram Mathematica*

```
DictionaryLookup["*w"]
```

or

```
DictionaryLookup[___ ~~ "w"] // Short
```

[image]

Comment: Because they use different databases?  I am not sure what kind of response you are expecting here.  It is not really a practical, answerable question.

Comment: @Szabolcs But we can doubt that the *alpha* and *Mathematica* will use different databases still.

Comment: @yode I think question above demonstrates that they do not use the same database.  The W|A words can be obtained using `WolframAlpha["words ending in w", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}, 
 PodStates -> {"Result__Show all"}]`.  There is also `WordData`: `Select[WordData[], StringMatchQ["*w"]]`. The results will not be all single words.